Make an internal function a stub
Lots of similar questions, but none that seem to fit.
Say there's a nodejs function:
async function handler(event) {
   await parseEvent(event)

   if(event.a)
      await doBusinessLogicA(event)
   else
      await doBusinessLogicB(event)

   return response
}

async function doBusinessLogicA(event){ ... }
async function doBusinessLogicB(event){ ... }

In theory, a unit test for "handler" shouldn't be testing businessLogic A or B. But how do I make those two calls do nothing?
The tests are written using mocha and sinon:
const sinon = require('sinon')

const { handler } = require('./location-whatever')

describe("Lambda tests", () => {
   describe("Handler", async () => {
      it("Should enter first if statement", async () => {
         let results = await handler({a: true})
      }
   }
}

I've tried using a sinon sandbox, and have also found a way manipulating the module.exports to become stubs but can't find a good way to restore them.
I know that this function doesn't do much, but for the sake of knowing the proper techniques I'm struggling to figure out how to do it "right."

You can use rewire package.

rewire adds a special setter and getter to modules so you can modify their behaviour for better unit testing.

Which means you can get/set the private functions defined in module scope.
e.g.
handler.js:
async function handler(event) {
    if (event.a) await doBusinessLogicA(event);
    else await doBusinessLogicB(event);

    return 'response';
}

async function doBusinessLogicA(event) {
    console.log('real implementation');
}
async function doBusinessLogicB(event) {
    console.log('real implementation');
}

module.exports = { handler };

handler.test.js:
const rewire = require('rewire');
const mod = rewire('./handler');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('78694661', () => {
    it('should pass when a is true', (done) => {
        mod
            .__with__({
                doBusinessLogicA: async () => console.log('doBusinessLogicA fake implementation'),
            })(() => mod.handler({ a: true }))
            .then((r) => {
                expect(r).to.be.equal('response');
                done();
            });
    });

    it('should pass when a is false', (done) => {
        mod
            .__with__({
                doBusinessLogicB: async () => console.log('doBusinessLogicB fake implementation'),
            })(() => mod.handler({ a: false }))
            .then((r) => {
                expect(r).to.be.equal('response');
                done();
            });
    });
});

Test result:
  78694661
doBusinessLogicA fake implementation
    √ should pass when a is true
doBusinessLogicB fake implementation
    √ should pass when a is false


  2 passing (8ms)

"rewire": "^4.0.1"
